# Bottom number coming from your Ghost in the "Nav Mode"

Tags: destiny-2

What is the bottom statistic coming out from your ghost in "Nav Mode?"

[image: Picture of ghost in Nav Mode]

Comment: Is that the "Gunsmith telemetry data" that doesn't seem to be documented anywhere?

Comment: To me it looks like the Kill Tracker Ghost which doesn't use the telemetry data. Anyway that data is like a low chance to get stuff to just turn into the gunsmith like materials.

Comment: Oh wait that may just be the PvE kill tracking.

Answer (score 4):

That number shows PVE kills. It's one of the extra features of the Kill Tracker Ghost. The top number shows your total Crucible kills, which, if I recall correctly, also counts your kills in Iron Banner and Trials of the Nine.